# Media en un csv

Tags: csv, ordenamiento, estadística, position, ordenar

Tengo un csv con dos parámetros, Frutas y el valor que se les da del 0 al 5, según diferentes clientes, con la siguiente forma:

```
Fruit | Value
Arándano | 3
Arándano | 4
Arándano | 1
Cereza | 5
Cereza | 2
Manzana | 1
Manzana | 1
Manzana | 2
Manzana | 3
Manzana | 1
```

Y quiero que me devuelva la media de cada fruta y a poder ser, que devuelva un "ranking" basado en esa media

Lo he intentado usando

```
import statistics as stats
print(stats.mean(?))
```

pero ha sido inútil, ya que para utilizarlo necesitaría, en este caso hacer tres prints, con tres listas de números diferentes, y para ello, tener que generar esas tres listas.

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Solo he conseguido llegar hasta aquí
`import statistics as stats
print(stats.mean(?))`

Donde me he dado cuenta que no es útil, ya que no es una única "lista"

Comment: Añádela, por favor, a la pregunta y así la comunidad podrá ver lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el módulo `pandas` para hacer el cálculo fácilmente usando dataframes:

- Para instalarla puedes usar `pip3`

```
pip3 install pandas
```

- Si estás en una distribución como ubuntu o debian puedes instalar pip:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install python3-pip
```

Dependiendo de la distribución que tengas ya puedes usar el comando.

En cuanto al código:

```
# Importas el módulo:
import pandas as pd

# Cargas el contenido del .csv en el dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('fruits.csv')

# Agrupas por la columna 'Fruit' y haces la media por 'Value'
result = df.groupby('Fruit')[['Value']].mean()

# Si imprimimos resultado:
print(result)
```

Obtenemos:

```
$-> python3 average.py 
             Value
Fruit             
Arándano  2.666667
Cereza    3.500000
Manzana   1.600000
```

Comment: Y para que esos resultados apareciesen en orden, habría que hacer guardarlo en un csv y hacer un sort después?

Comment: No sería necesario. Intercambia el orden y verás que ya te lo imprimirá en orden alfabético ascendente A -> Z por lo que no tendrás que realizar ninguna operación de `sort` para ordenarlo.